# How to insert column data from one table into another in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to insert `new_file_name` column data from `document_image_volume1_rename_temp` table into the `document_image_volume1_rename` table. Both tables have a column  `document_image_id`.

```
USE myDatabase

INSERT INTO document_image_volume1_rename (new_file_name)
   SELECT 
      new_file_name
   FROM  
      document_image_volume1_rename_temp
   WHERE 
      document_image_volume1_rename.document_image_id = document_image_volume1_rename_temp.document_image_id
```

Here's the error message:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
>   The multi-part identifier "document_image_volume1_rename.document_image_id" could not be bound.

Comment: So would I be correct to conclude that you don't actually want to **insert** new rows into `document_image_volume1_rename`?? That you actually want to **update** the value (from empty or value to the new value) in the **existing row**?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are actually looking for is an `UPDATE` query not an `INSERT` query. If you don't want to add new rows but just modify a column in existing rows, try this:

```
UPDATE t2
SET t2.new_file_name = t1.new_file_name
FROM document_image_volume1_rename_temp t1 INNER JOIN document_image_volume1_rename t2 ON t1.document_image_id = t2.document_image_id
```

A handy reference on `UPDATE` query syntax by DBMS can be found in [Eric's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1293347/3076048).